# sync older photos and videos on Google+ instant upload

Tags: google-plus

I use an android 4.2 phone and google plus instant upload to sync media to the cloud.
I notice that only my new photos are being synced.

Is there a way to sync older photos and videos on my device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://support.google.com/plus/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=2769098

Instant Upload is designed to upload photos taken while you're signed into the app and the Instant Upload feature is turned on. Use Upload all to upload photos already on your mobile device.

To use  the Upload all feature:

- Open the Google+ app
- Tap Menu  and select Settings
- If your device has a physical Menu button, press Menu and select Settings
- Tap Instant Upload
- Tap Upload all to initiate upload.

Keep in mind that the process of cataloging and uploading the photos on your device may take some time depending upon the number of photos on your device and the speed of your data connection.